# Markloigc : Escape regular expression in fn:replace

Tags: regex, xquery, marklogic

Can anyone help me how to escape regular expression in fn:replace()

My actual code look like,

**Request**

```
let $x := "/SLR/[2009] 3 SLR(R) 0327.xml"
return
(
  fn:replace( $x, $x, "Expected Value")
)
```

**Response**: Unexpected response since it has regular expression terms in.

```
/SLR/[2009] 3 SLR(R) 0327.xml
```

If i escape regular expression manually, i got the result as expected.

like,

**Request**

```
let $x := "/SLR/[2009] 3 SLR(R) 0327.xml"
return
(
  fn:replace( $x, "/SLR/\[2009\] 3 SLR\(R\) 0327.xml", "Expected Value")
)
```

**Response**:

```
Expected Value
```

My problem is i cant do manually for 1000 of files i had.

Can any one please help me how to make it easier?

Comment: Are you sure you need regex for this? You can check for substring here.

Comment: @karthik manchala thanks for your suggestion, i actually want to replace the  xml name. i think fn:replace() would be better option for me in my case. I got the expected output with the below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functx library provides a method to do this:

```
functx:escape-for-regex('[abc]') \[abc\]
```

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_escape-for-regex.html